# Raspberry Pi Connect to 3G modem instead of ethernet

Tags: raspbian, internet

On startup, I have ethernet and a 3G modem connected to my raspberry pi. How do I set the pi so that it connects to the 3G modem instead of the ethernet? I am using raspbian.

Comment: You should specify which operating system you are using.

Comment: @goldilocks I am using raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work using wvdial, and by modifying a few files. In the rc.local file I used `sudo wvdial &` to start the modem on startup. After, I used `ifdown --force eth0` and `ifup --force ppp0` to make sure the 3G modem was being used instead of the direct ethernet connection. In my /etc/network/interfaces file I added `iface ppp0 init wvdial`. The result is that on startup the modem is used even if the ethernet is attached. As well, if the modem is removed, the ethernet is used, and if the modem is plugged back in, the 3G modem is used.